# How to refresh view with the next GIF in the array

Tags: swiftui, sdwebimage

Once the button has been tapped I want to refresh the currently displayed GIF with the next GIF in the array. I am using [SDWebImageSwiftUI](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI) to display the GIF. The following error message is shown when I try to change the array value:

> Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(url: URL?,
>   options: SDWebImageOptions)'

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImage
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct TrainingView : View {
    @State private var forwardButtonTapped = false
    @Published var currentIndex = 0
    var GIFS = ["https://media3.giphy.com/media/xULW8v7LtZrgcaGvC0/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611cabeafc835b67239aa3fa3f3abc3df4322c3e4ea&rid=giphy.gif", "https://media1.giphy.com/media/6tHy8UAbv3zgs/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611cabeafc835b67239aa3fa3f3abc3df4322c3e4ea&rid=giphy.gif"]

    var body: some View {
            VStack(){

            AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: GIFS[currentIndex]), options: [.progressiveLoad])
                .scaledToFit()

            Button(action:{
                self.forwardButtonTapped.toggle()
            }) {Image("forwardButton")}

            if forwardButtonTapped {
                self.currentIndex += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought using `@Published` would refresh the view with the new GIF once the value has been changed on `currentIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know when trying sample in [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/), in body of SwiftUI, we can just render UI, cannot write logic code like `self.currentIndex += 1`. So when you write logic code here, this will appear some weird error. Just put this code into Button action. I tried your code, edit somewhere and it worked.

```
struct TrainingView : View {
    @State private var forwardButtonTapped = false
    @State var currentIndex = 0
    var GIFS = ["https://media3.giphy.com/media/xULW8v7LtZrgcaGvC0/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611cabeafc835b67239aa3fa3f3abc3df4322c3e4ea&rid=giphy.gif", "https://media1.giphy.com/media/6tHy8UAbv3zgs/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611cabeafc835b67239aa3fa3f3abc3df4322c3e4ea&rid=giphy.gif"]

    var body: some View {
            VStack(){

            AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: GIFS[currentIndex]), options: [.progressiveLoad])
                .scaledToFit()

            Button(action:{
                self.currentIndex += 1
            }) {Text("CLICK @@@@@")}.frame(width: 150, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
}
```